# How to read local text file in chrome without using a local webserver?

Tags: javascript

I have done the XMLHTTPRequest method and the Fetch API method too nothing works on chrome? Help me please?

I have also tried the --access-allow-files flag it works. But i dont want to follow this approach.

Comment: *"But i dont want to follow this approach"* well you are out of luck....

Comment: "I have also tried the --access-allow-files flag it works. But i dont want to follow this approach." - without explaining _why_ this isn't sufficient we likely won't be able to help you with this.

Comment: The browser has security that you can not access files on the file system. You mentioned the two solutions.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well for my application the user wouldnt be able to do this everytime. He or she just wants to open chrome normally and load the files Obviously this approach would be so non-user friendly where one has to pass through a flag everytime to open chrome :/

Comment: @epascarello So there isnt any other solution? Everything works fine on Mozilla but everyone mostly uses chrome so i have to provide a solution for this browser too i guess? And its kind of a requirement too for my application